# Difference between init and config in use-package

Tags: package, use-package

I have a configuration like this:

```
(use-package html-mode
  :mode "\\.html\\'"
  :config
  (progn
    (add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'turn-off-auto-fill)))
```

Now when I go and visit an HTML file, I observe that `auto-fill` is not turned off. But if I use `:init` instead of `:config`, `auto-fill` gets turned off. So my question is when are the commands under `:config` executed ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

They are different if the package is deferred, i.e. not loaded until it is needed. In that case `:init` will be executed at the time your emacs file is first read, but `:config` will be executed at the time the package is actually loaded.

In your example, the use of `mode` implicitly defers loading the package. You have configured the package to be loaded the first time an html file is visited.

You could use `:demand` to make sure the package is always loaded at startup, but more likely what you want to do here is put your hook in `:init`.

From the docstring:

```
:init Code to run when `use-package' form evals.
```

Since you're putting this in your user-init file, that basically means it will run at startup.

```
:config Runs if and when package loads.
```

So, not run until the package is actually being loaded..

```
:defer Defer loading of package -- automatic if :commands, :bind, :bind*,  :mode or :interpreter are used.
```

Note the list of things that automatically make a package deferred. Basically if you tell `use-package` the conditions in which you need this package, it assumes you don't want to load it until those conditions arise.

```
:demand Prevent deferred loading in all cases.
```

Make sure the package is loaded at startup, regardless of what other options you've specified.

**Update**

Revisiting this based on the recent comments... What I said above is all true, but I don't think it correctly answers the question. The root problem here is actually that `html-mode` is not a package, but rather a mode defined by the package `sgml-mode`. This works as expected for me:

```
(use-package sgml-mode
  :mode ("\\.html\\'" . html-mode)
  :config (add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'turn-off-auto-fill))
```

In the original example, the `:config` expression never gets evaluated because a package named `html-mode` never gets loaded. Moving the same expression to `:init` works because init code is always evaluated, regardless of whether the package ever gets loaded.

Comment: See [Semantics of :init is now consistent](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/#semantics-of-init-is-now-consistent)

Comment: @npostavs Thanks, worth noting. I haven't yet moved to use-package 2.0 myself. For one thing, I use `:idle` pretty extensively and haven't looked into the impact of ":idle has been removed".

Comment: I still don't understand why, when he visits an HTML file and triggers the package to load, `auto-fill` is not turned off, i.e. the config code didn't run.  I have the same problem.

Comment: @KenWilliams Your issue is with html-mode as well? I think the actual problem here is that `html-mode` is not a package. At least in my current version of Emacs, `html-mode` is defined in the package `sgml-mode`. So if you tell `use-package` to do something when a package named `html-mode` is loaded that code never runs because no such package is ever loaded. You need to put html-mode setup in a `(use-package sgml-mode ....)`.

Comment: Sorry - my issue is with `org-mode`, not `html-mode`.  A similar issue there is that the package is called `org-mode`, but the ELPA package is called `org`.  Maybe that's confusing it (or me)?

Comment: Right - you'd need to `(use-package org :config ....)`, since org.el is providing the feature `org`.

Comment: I still couldn't figure it out, so I posted a new question: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17710/use-package-with-config-to-set-variables .  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11):

This example made me much easy to understand the difference between `:init` and `:config`. Let's take an example of `ace-window` package (but this can be any package). Put this in your `init.el` file:

```
(use-package ace-window
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :config
  (progn
    (message "ace window: hello world")))
```

Now open your emacs and see in the `*Messages*` buffer to see if there any `hello world` message. You won't be able to find any because the package is deferred. Now change from `config` to `init`:

```
(use-package ace-window
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :init
  (progn
    (message "ace window: hello world")))
```

Now close and re-open emacs and inspect the `*Messages*` buffer. You will see the message `ace window: hello world` because the code is run no matter what when `:init` is given. In the case of `config` it will be only run when that package is loaded.

Comment: that helps, just a side question, what is the difference then between the keyword `:init` and `:preface` based on your example?

Comment: @doctorate: `:preface` is run even if the package in question is **disabled** whereas `:init` is only run when a package is enabled.