# `use-package` with :config to set variables

Tags: org-mode, init-file, use-package

I'm trying to use `use-package` to set up my `org-mode` initialization.  I have the following in my `~/.emacs` file:

```
(use-package org-mode
  :mode "\\.org$"
  :ensure org
  :config
  (progn
    (setq org-log-done 'time)
    (setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)
    (setq org-export-babel-evaluate nil)
    (setq org-html-validation-link nil)
    ;; ... more stuff
  )
)
```

None of that `:config` initialization stuff is getting run, though.  Do I have the package names wrong or something?  I get a bit confused on package names vs. ELPA names vs. invocation commands....

Comment: Take a look at `org.el` and you'll see toward the end: `(provide 'org)`. That symbol (`org`) is what you would use to load the package, as in: `(require 'org)`. That is ultimately what `use-package` is doing, just with some useful stuff around it. A given package can define lots of modes so the package and mode names are not always the same. This is really the same issue as the other question about `html-mode` being defined by the `sgml-mode` package.

Comment: The "other question" @glucas mentions: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/10396/8899

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The below would work. For the sake of clarity, I am using `:ensure org-plus-contrib` which deviates a bit from the example in your question.

```el
(use-package org
  :mode (("\\.org$" . org-mode))
  :ensure org-plus-contrib
  :config
  (progn
    ;; config stuff
    ))
```

Here are some explanation notes for the above:

- `(use-package FEATURE-NAME`

  - `FEATURE-NAME` is what goes in the `(provide ..)` line of a package. For `org-mode`, that line is `(provide 'org)`.
- `:mode ((FILE-REGEXP . MAJOR-MODE))`

  - `FILE-REGEXP` is the regular expression for which you want a particular major mode to be enabled. You had that correct: `"\\.org$"`.
  - `MAJOR-MODE` is the name of the major mode that you want to enable (including the `-mode` part of the major mode name). In this case, the major mode name is `org-mode`.
  - The style `:mode (FILE-REGEXP)` that you used would only work if `FEATURE-NAME` and `MAJOR-MODE` are the exact same. Example: `cperl-mode`.
- `:ensure PACKAGE-NAME`

  - `PACKAGE-NAME` is what I see listed in the package list (`M-x package-list-packages`). For clarity, in my solution above, we are installing the `org-plus-contrib`<sup>1</sup> package. *This is to demonstrate the feature name, major mode and the actual package name do not have to be the exact same. And also I prefer installing that instead of plain `org-mode` as you get all the `contrib/` package goodies too! :)*

---

<sup>1</sup> You will need to add `(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)` to your emacs config in order to install `org-plus-contrib`. See the [official org-mode installation page](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html) for more info.

---

**Note**

The best way to make the above `use-package` snippet to work is to save it to your emacs config first, then delete prior Package Manager installed versions of `org`, and then restart emacs.

Comment: Thanks - I'm still having trouble with one aspect, getting org's R support to work using `org-babel-do-load-languages` in this context, it gives the error `Error (use-package): org :config: Invalid function: org-babel-header-args-safe-fn`.  Other languages (e.g. `sh` or `perl` or `emacs-lisp`) seem to work fine.

Comment: That looks like an unrelated issue. Are you using that macro as intended? You can learn more about it by doing `C-h f org-babel-header-args-safe-fn`. Also you don't have that code snippet in your question. So it's difficult to guess what's going on.

Comment: It seems to be this problem: https://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg98818.html .  Not sure how to resolve it yet.  My full config is here: https://gist.github.com/kenahoo/8bca2ecc5cbe6e48a91c and commenting out the `(R . t)` line stops the error.  So yeah, unrelated issue I think.  Might need to open *another* question...

Comment: Looks like my org-mode itself broke with the latest update.  Fixed that by doing `emacs -Q` to start clean, carefully load my `'package` configuration, uninstalling `org` and `org-plus-contrib`, then re-installing them.  The problem is explained here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13576/8899

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Probably installing `org-plus-contrib` messed up your org installation and you ended up having a mix of versions. btw, you need to install just `org-plus-contrib`. You do not need to install the separate `org` package too.

Comment: `org-plus-contrib` isn't maintained anymore. Now, there are two packages: `org` in GnuELPA and `org-contrib` in NonGnuELPA. See https://orgmode.org/elpa.html

Answer (score 4):

With the caveat that I haven't used `use-package` before, I believe you want `org` rather than `org-mode`.  I'm basing this on the fact that, on my Emacs, `(package-installed-p 'org-mode)` returns nil while `(package-installed-p 'org)` does not.